# AlCl3 and water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrons

While reading Clayden's (et al) Organic Chemistry I stumbled upon a reaction on page 120 that I just fail to wrap my brain around. It describes a reaction of AlCl3 with water and states that, quote, "Eventually alumina (Al2O3) is formed."

Here's the said reaction
[image]

Now...
I was trying to understand what the intermediates are between the AlCl3H2O and Al2O3 and the best I can do (and bear with me, I might be wrong) is an idea that the negative [Al]- can transfer an electron to Cl which then deprotonates the [H2O]+ group leaving HCl as a by-product. Repeat the cycle three times and I get Al(OH)3 with an empty π orbital as in the starting aluminium chloride. I guess maybe it can be hydrolysed further to give a [Al(OH)4]- ion but then what?

To add to my confusion a quick scout on google tells me that AlCl3 can decompose into Al2O3 but it requires a lot of heat, well above the boiling point of water, which is nowhere mentioned in the textbook. Besides if I'm correct that HCl is a by-product here, then from what I understand it would quickly react with Al2O3 in presence of heat to form AlCl3 again, eventually reaching some sort of equilibrium.

All in all I would appreciate some help in understanding what's going on here.

Comment: You don't learn Inorganic chemistry from a book on Organic chemistry. Sure, organic chemists have their own use for AlCl3, and know a thing or two about its properties, but their perspective is distorted. That being said, in reality AlCl3 won't hydrolyze all the way to Al(OH)3, unless you apply a good deal of heating.

Comment: *For the purpose learning organic chemistry*, the point to retain should be: water (or, any molecule with an $\ce{-OH}$ group) reacts with the Lewis acid $\ce{AlCl3}$ to quench it.  In other words, count this former $\ce{AlCl3}$ out, it can no longer catalyze your Friedel-Crafts reaction. And not only $\ce{-OH}$ groups with an «acidic proton» undergo this reaction, only that the typical work-up uses water.